# Dealing with negative buffers in ArcGIS Desktop when original polygon is narrower than buffer width?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, arcgis-10.6

I am having problems creating a negative 75m buffer with polygons which have regions narrower than 150m. To add some context, I have polygons which are created automatically out of enginnering data which are then defined as potential high-risk flooding areas. These geometries are notorious for their unwieldlyness. I have to use these Polygons in a 1:50000 scale map - but am not permitted to generalize...which is rather short-sighted. Below is a screenshot:

[image: Polygon Structure]

There are holes and very narrow areas making inside buffering impossible.

I need to buffer the polygons with a 62m buffer as we have a strict symbology guideline. My workaround was to convert the polygons to lines and buffer them. This works to a certain extent. The only problem is the line orientation. The Polygons need to be buffered inside. If I buffer lines I have to stipulate whether the line will be buffered to the left or right. This is not the same for each line and thus I have to work with each line individually to find out it's orientation.

Is there a workflow to somehow force the buffer to be produced and then dissolve and clip it with the original polygon outline?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

Comment: I think this needs a picture of a polygon on which you are not able to get your desired result, along with what you want vs what you get, and the parameters used for the undesirable result.

Comment: Feature to Line, buffer line with positive values and side type = Right or Left (right seems to work for me)

Comment: Agree with @PolyGeo, what are your polygons? Are they simple building foot prints or highly tortuous polygons with holes and therefore inner rings? Need more information.

Comment: Not a solution but a comment. The opensource software SAGA-GIS handels the problem perfectly. It has created an inner puffer of all the polygons without crashing due to the narrow geometries. Free software which outperforms ESRI.

Comment: So what was the problem? Were you getting errors? I just tried running the buffer tool on some polygon data (rivers with islands) using a negative buffer size wide enough to collapse the geometry and it ran without error creating internal buffers when the river was wide enough. But I had a small sample dataset.

Comment: The problem is that ArcGIS 10.6 crashes every time without errors.

Comment: Have you tried Check/Repair Geometry on this data?  By "crashes every time without errors" do you mean that ArcMap closes without even a "Serious Application Error" dialog?  What happens when you take just one or a few of these "holes and very narrow areas" out into a separate test dataset?  Can you reproduce this on anything less than your total data?